# With what additional assumption, would a connected space be path connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a connected space.

What additional condition on $X$ would imply that $X$ is path-connected?

The only one I know is by assuming $X$ is an open subspace of a normed space $V$.

What else would imply this?

Comment: Local path-connectedness?

Comment: Actually asking that any point has a path connected neighbourhood is enough

Comment: @GFR: In that case, components coincide with path components. In particular a connected space with that property is path connected. You should make your comment an answer, as that condition is provably the weakest condition.

Answer (score 1):

A connected space $X$ is path connected if and only if every point of $X$ has a path connected neighbourhood.

One direction is  obvious as $X$ is path connected it then is a path connected neighbourhood of any point.

For the other direction note that if every point has a path connected neighbourhood then the path components of $X$ are open and therefore also closed. But the only clopen sets in a connected space are the empty set and the whole space hence $X$ has only one path component and is path connected.